# How can a game created in Unity can run on an Android device?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I'm new using Unity and, if I understood correctly, it works using C# language. Android devices can only run Java applications cause that's the work of its virtual machine: the Dalvik. So how can this be done with the feature of this program to "compile" to Android???

Comment: Dalvik isn't the only VM that can be run on Android. See MonoTouch/MonoDroid.

Comment: Dalvik is not a "Java" VM - it doesn't execute Java bytecode.  Java apps go through a conversion to become Davlik programs.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Android devices can also run **native** code written normally in C or C++.

The Unity application written in C# is compiled to .NET bytecodes. When Unity builds an Android app, it includes a .NET bytecode interpreter in native code, based on [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page). When you run the app, the interpreter is run to execute the bytecodes. That's how it can run on Android.

Comment: Thanks @yuku - does the same happen for other plataforms such as iOS too?