# How unity make games by c# and run them in many operating systems?

Tags: unity-game-engine

**Unity** builds games using **c#** for many OS such as **android**.
Android OS is written in **java** and it's not include **c# compiler**.
So how unity can make games by c# and run them in android OS?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can a game created in Unity can run on an Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9305111/how-can-a-game-created-in-unity-can-run-on-an-android-device)

Answer (score 1):

Android *is not* written in Java! At its core Android is a Linux kernel, with a custom userland. Part of that userland is *Dalvik*, Android's JRE. However Android can also run *native* code.

C# is just a programming language, that is part of the .net/CLI ecosystem. Xamarin developed a .net runtime called *Mono*, and there is a port of Mono for Android that runs as native code.

So by bundling up a Xamarin Mono runtime, together with the compiled code you can run things written for .net on Android.